# String in triple quotation won't attach to variable

Tags: python, string, indentation, quotations

I keep getting this error

"  File "ex24.py", line 4
    poem = """
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax "

in this code:

```
 print ("Let's practice everthing.")
 print ('You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

poem = """
    \tThe lovely world
    with logic so firmly planted
    cannot discern \n the needs of love 
    nor comprehend passion from intuition
    and requires an explanation
    \n\t\twhere there is none.
    """

print ("--------------")
print (poem)
print ("--------------")


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
print ("This should be five: %s" % (five))

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_bean, jars, crates


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula (start_point)

print ("With a starting point of: %d" % (start_point))
print ("We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates))

start_point = start_point / 10

print ("We can also do that this way:")
print ("We'd have %d beans, %d jars and %d crates." % (secret_formula(start_point))
```

I dont understand which error I am making, in my poem variable since I can
make the code work without error when I make the variable work in a file for itself?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: It's just training in python principles. Im trying to figure out how the code works myself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end of your second line.  See [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFj7FuwzAMRPcA-YeDF7eL_6B_0LFLAS2KTMdCZVKl6Dj9-9J2gXIQQN3D3bFqZsNL907WN1SNyXIi0IPU5sz3oXu9XuoJ9Z-yhn4EE40wwRfLhtDfZDVQS7FSw5ZtRgiwORpGQWDHt5LZtcgjgsHirQ2927qx0II3dF13vcAn2MdMKPKg8oNNtIzn_-Fa5J4TmmDKurheS2SjPyJFZvHE3BIp77HmTnvTBpkOS5wkiyLJUpVm8kI1tpaFMaks8DPXbL6e6F5Y6XvNerQHPffM-A8EDhZsm0lpz_M3Nw9gGk7dD_sFkt9x9w==&lang=sage).

```
print ("Let's practice everthing.")
print ('You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.')

poem = """
    \tThe lovely world
    with logic so firmly planted
    cannot discern \n the needs of love 
    nor comprehend passion from intuition
    and requires an explanation
    \n\t\twhere there is none.
    """
```

Comment: Man... Sorry for asking such a question, I dont know how I could miss that. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem - we've all been there!